# How to install a deprecated extension in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to install an extension that is now deprecated. any way to side load the extension ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download extension in .vsix format from https://www.vsixhub.com/ or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

Then

1. Open VS Code and go to the Extensions panel on the left-hand side.
2. Click on the ellipsis icon (three dots) at the top of the panel and select "Install from VSIX..." from the drop-down menu.
3. Navigate to the directory where you have saved the deprecated extension's VSIX file and select it.
4. VS Code will then install the deprecated extension.

Answer (score 1):

Discover the identifier of the extension in the Marketplace website. There's usually a link to it at the External Resources section in the Extensions panel.

Launch VS Code **Quick Open (Ctrl+P)** and type:

```
ext install <identifier>
```

For instance: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.rubocop-lsp

It already shows how to do it in the website:
[image]